# Some questions regarding Visual Studio Property Sheets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have to support projects with VS 2010 as well as VS 2012. Even if VS 2012 can read and write projects that are usable with VS 2010, there are reasons to (sometimes) prefer VS2010, since (e.g.) it has support for setup projects and macros, while VS2012 hasn't. Furthermore, upgrade to VS2012 would require to install new redistributable components at the customer side which is not generally possible in any case or will not help (Qt 4.8, for instance, only provides libraries linked against VS 2010 redistributables).

Unfortunately there seems to be an incompatibility if both versions are installed side by side: both are set up to use property sheets from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0` but they may become different when written from either version of VS.

For instance, it seems both VS use different variables to refer to the Windows SDK location. This is actually not a problem as long as one doesn't need to add another include files directory or libraries folder. Until then the property sheets don't contain specific settings at all and inherited values are used (which work in each VS). However, as soon as I add some directory for, say, Boost, inherited settings are copied to the property sheet (which contain for example `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)` or `$(WindowsSdkDir)include`, respecitively). Now VS 2012 doesn't understand those location variables of VS 2010 and vice versa.

This situation leads to the following questions:

1. Can I edit the "source" of inheritance? Currently, Visual Studio 2012 writes `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)` to the property sheet, VS 2010 writes `$(WindowsSdkDir)include`, instead.  It's similar for library files. The other version cannot include files like "windows.h" anymore. So well, one could "merge" files manually, but this seems not "otherwise it can't find files like `Windows.h`.
2. How can I determine what variables such as `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)` or `$(WindowsSdkDir)` expand to at all?
3. How can I change which property sheets are used for new projects automagically? Do I have to add my own property sheets always manually? If it could be done, you could have different property sheets for debug and release modes which is as I read an often mentioned requirement.
4. What's the simplest way to add a property sheet to a project? Having to load it through the "Property Manager" each time seems a bit annoying.
5. and 4. would be especially important for including the settings in version control.

Comment: Why not convert the 2010 projects to 2012?

Comment: @Richard what about people who don't use 2012? Look at the GNOME's git projects. Thy contain solutions for 2003, 2005, 2008, 2010, and 2012 (usually just 2005, 2008, and 2010)

Comment: Flag for `alt.se.prog`.

Comment: @Cole: most VS2010 SP1 projects can be opened by VS2012, edited, then opened again by VS2010 SP1.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what the service projects do. But you can't open a 2012 solution/project in vanilla 2010. That's what it seems the OP is asking.

Comment: You can do just about the same - create the project in VS2010SP1, then you can open it in both. It may even be possible to start with a VS2012 project - I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: Please post a comment when downvoting whoever does - I'd like to know what's wrong about the matter or the question.